# Customizing Bootflat in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bower, bootflat

I have installed bootflat using bower. The instaltion location was set up as "vendor/assets/components/Bootflat". I have also included the relevant files in my application.scss, application.js and application.haml files. I assume that it's being included correctly because everything is working as expected.

My question now is, how do I customize scss variables used in Bootflat? Here is my current code in application.scss (app/assets/stylesheets):

```
$alert-primary:red !important;
@import "Bootflat/bootflat/scss/bootflat";
```

"$alert-primary" is a variable that's already used by Bootflat and I want to redefine it. How/Where would I redefine this? I get that what I'm doing above is probably not right as the variable is defined by a Bootflat file, which would mean that my definition above is overwritten. But I also do not want to change the scss code in the origin files? What is the best solution? Will it be to copy and paste the code for a specific component into my app's stylesheet and then redefine a component after importing bootflat (this should overwrite the original definition by Bootflat)?